# How to use .findAll and find records from two different tables and a self reference?

Tags: mysql, node.js, database, sequelize.js, sequelize-cli

I'm working with two tables in particular. Users and Friends. Users has a bunch of information that defines the User whereas Friends has two columns aside from id: user_id and friend_id where both of them are a reference to the User table.

I'm trying to find all of the users friends in as little calls to the db as possible and I currently have 2. One to retrieve the id of a user first from a request, then another to Friends where I compare the IDs from the first call and then a third call that passes the array of friends and find all of them in the Users table. This already feels like overkill and I think that with associations, there has to be a better way.

Modification of the tables unfortunately is not an option.

One thing that I saw from "http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/querying.html#relations---associations"

I tried but got an interesting error.. when trying to repurpose the code snippet in the link under Relations/Associations, I get "user is associated to friends multiple times. To identify the correct association, you must use the 'as' keyword to specify the alias of the association you want to include."

```
      const userRecord = await User.findOne({
        where: { id }
      })

      const friendsIDs = await Friends.findAll({
        attributes: ["friend_id"],
        where: {
          user_id: userRecord.id
        }
      }).then(results => results.map(result => result.friend_id));

      const Sequelize = require("sequelize");
      const Op = Sequelize.Op;

      return await User.findAll({
        where: {
          id: { [Op.in]: friendsIDs }
        },
      });
```

Above for my use case works. I'm just wondering if there are ways to cut down the number of calls to the db.

Comment: Why you are calling this query, as you already have the user id. 

const userRecord = await User.findOne({
        where: { id }
      })


Did you try using join on friends table, if so please mention the query that you used ?

Did you added user_id and friend_id as foreign key in friend table ?

Comment: Why not use raw SQL query? Because your requirement is not needing any associations data of final findAll. SELECT * FROM users where id IN (SuB QUERY). Even if don't want to use raw SQL completely, you can use - where: Sequelize.literal("(Sub Query)");

Comment: @PankajJindal yes user_id and friend_id are foreign keys in the friend table. I'm not sure I understand the confusion. The front end makes a call to a specific back end endpoint and passes the user_id to search for friends

Comment: @user3026715 is your issue resolved or you are still facing it ?

Comment: Turns out Sequelize handles this for you if you have the proper associations in place so yes, it was a one liner user.getFriends() for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out Sequelize handles this for you if you have the proper associations in place so yes, it was a one liner user.getFriends() for me.